# Maximum number of duplicates

Tags: c++, string, c++11, duplicates

Errors:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
cannot convert '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits > >::value_type {aka std::basic_string}' to 'int' in assignment  duplicatedWords.cpp /duplicatedWords/src    line 42 C/C++ Problem
cannot convert '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits > >::value_type {aka std::basic_string}' to 'int' in initialization  duplicatedWords.cpp /duplicatedWords/src    line 37 C/C++ Problem
cannot convert 'std::basic_string' to 'int' in initialization duplicatedWords.cpp /duplicatedWords/src    line 40 C/C++ Problem
no match for 'operator>' (operand types are '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits > >::value_type {aka std::basic_string}' and 'int') duplicatedWords.cpp /duplicatedWords/src    line 41 C/C++ Problem

```
/*
Write a program to read strings from standard input
looking for duplicated words. The program should find places in the input
where one word is followed immediately by itself. Keep track of the  largest
number of times a single repetition occurs and which word is repeated.   Print
the maximum number of duplicates, or else print a message saying that no
word was repeated. For example, if the input is

how now now now brown cow cow

the output should indicate that the word now occurred three times.
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
cout << "Please enter your words " << endl;
    string words;
    vector<string> vec;

    while(cin>>words && words != "qu"){
        vec.push_back(words);

    }

    int max = vec[0];
    int result = 0;

    for(int i: vec){
        if(vec[i] > max){
        max = vec[i];
        result = i;
        }
    }

    cout<<result<<endl;
return 0;
```

}

Comment: I am lost on how i can find the maximum duplicate

Comment: First, you have a string vector and you're doing some string things with it. Ok. Then, suddenly, the rest of the code is like the vector contains integer, which can be assigned to `int` and compared with `>`. What are you doing?!

Comment: What will happen if the user enters `qu` as the first input? Handle that case gracefully.

Comment: To put @deviantfan comment perhaps more simply, `vec` contains strings and not integers, therefore you cannot grab an int from it here: `int max = vec[0];`

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

If the input is sorted, which I think your program assumes, then the following modifications done to your code below will work. However, if the input is unsorted then you should use hash tables or sort the input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int max = 0;
    int result = 0;
    unsigned int rep_count = 1;
    string words;
    vector<string> vec;

    cout << "Please enter your words " << endl;
    while(cin>>words && words != "qu"){
        vec.push_back(words);
    }

    if (!vec.size())
        return 0;

    for(unsigned int i = 1; i < vec.size(); i++){
        if (vec[i] == vec[i-1]) {
            rep_count++;
        } else {
            rep_count = 1;
        }
        if (rep_count > max) {
            result = i;
            max = rep_count;
        }
    }
    cout<<"Word = "<<vec[result]<<", Repitition = "<<max<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```